# Rails- starting rails server 3.0.3 for android-market-crawler project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have installed `Ruby 1.8.7` and downloaded `rubygems-1.4.0.zip` , unzipped it into Ruby187 folder. Then I ran the following command

```
gem install rails --version 3.0.3
```

I want to use [Android-marketplace-crawler](http://code.google.com/p/android-marketplace-crawler/) project which contains two folders `server` and `crawler`. One of the project requirements is `Ruby on Rails 3` for which I have installed Rails server. But when I run `rails server` on command prompt, I get this problem

```
Usage 
rails new APP_PATH [options]
....
....
```

Gemfile.lock in server folder

```
GIT
  remote: git://github.com/adamcooper/vestal_versions
  revision: 6273df533f85014062e346cb1807b0531a809ee2
  specs:
    vestal_versions (1.2.2)
      activerecord (>= 3.0.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0.0)

GEM
  remote: http://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    abstract (1.0.0)
    actionmailer (3.0.3)
      actionpack (= 3.0.3)
      mail (~> 2.2.9)
    actionpack (3.0.3)
      activemodel (= 3.0.3)
      activesupport (= 3.0.3)
      builder (~> 2.1.2)
      erubis (~> 2.6.6)
      i18n (~> 0.4)
      rack (~> 1.2.1)
      rack-mount (~> 0.6.13)
      rack-test (~> 0.5.6)
      tzinfo (~> 0.3.23)
    activemodel (3.0.3)
      activesupport (= 3.0.3)
      builder (~> 2.1.2)
      i18n (~> 0.4)
    activerecord (3.0.3)
      activemodel (= 3.0.3)
      activesupport (= 3.0.3)
      arel (~> 2.0.2)
      tzinfo (~> 0.3.23)
    activeresource (3.0.3)
      activemodel (= 3.0.3)
      activesupport (= 3.0.3)
    activesupport (3.0.3)
    arel (2.0.7)
    builder (2.1.2)
    erubis (2.6.6)
      abstract (>= 1.0.0)
    i18n (0.5.0)
    mail (2.2.15)
      activesupport (>= 2.3.6)
      i18n (>= 0.4.0)
      mime-types (~> 1.16)
      treetop (~> 1.4.8)
    mime-types (1.16)
    mysql2 (0.2.6)
    paperclip (2.3.8)
      activerecord
      activesupport
    polyglot (0.3.1)
    rack (1.2.1)
    rack-mount (0.6.13)
      rack (>= 1.0.0)
    rack-test (0.5.7)
      rack (>= 1.0)
    rails (3.0.3)
      actionmailer (= 3.0.3)
      actionpack (= 3.0.3)
      activerecord (= 3.0.3)
      activeresource (= 3.0.3)
      activesupport (= 3.0.3)
      bundler (~> 1.0)
      railties (= 3.0.3)
    railties (3.0.3)
      actionpack (= 3.0.3)
      activesupport (= 3.0.3)
      rake (>= 0.8.7)
      thor (~> 0.14.4)
    rake (0.8.7)
    thor (0.14.6)
    treetop (1.4.9)
      polyglot (>= 0.3.1)
    tzinfo (0.3.24)
    will_paginate (2.3.15)

PLATFORMS
  ruby

DEPENDENCIES
  mysql2
  paperclip
  rails (= 3.0.3)
  vestal_versions!
  will_paginate
```

Gemfile in server folder is :

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.0.3'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

gem 'mysql2'
gem 'paperclip'
gem 'will_paginate'
gem 'vestal_versions', :git => 'git://github.com/adamcooper/vestal_versions'


# Use unicorn as the web server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Deploy with Capistrano
# gem 'capistrano'

# To use debugger (ruby-debug for Ruby 1.8.7+, ruby-debug19 for Ruby 1.9.2+)
# gem 'ruby-debug'
# gem 'ruby-debug19'

# Bundle the extra gems:
# gem 'bj'
# gem 'nokogiri'
# gem 'sqlite3-ruby', :require => 'sqlite3'
# gem 'aws-s3', :require => 'aws/s3'

# Bundle gems for the local environment. Make sure to
# put test-only gems in this group so their generators
# and rake tasks are available in development mode:
# group :development, :test do
#   gem 'webrat'
# end
```

I have seen all the threads on SO but none of them is solving my problem.

I ran following command

```
bundle install
```

It gives me following error:

```
Fetching git://github.com/adamcooper/vestal_versions
Unfortunately, a fatal error has occurred. Please see the Bundler.
```